# Django, set ChoiceField in form, after creation

Tags: django

I want to display a form with some customized user data in it. More specifically I want to fill a `forms.ChoiceField` with different data for each user.

This is my `Form`:

```
class WallPostForm(forms.Form):
    text = forms.CharField(label=u'', widget=TinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 70, 'rows': 5}))
    relates_to = forms.ChoiceField(label=u'Relates to', choices=[], widget=forms.Select(), required=False)

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.fields['relates_to'] = forms.ChoiceField(label=u'Relates to', choices=data, widget=forms.Select(), required=False)
        super(WallPostForm, self).__init__()
```

And this is how I am calling this:

```
user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
data = UserTopics.objects.filter(user=user, result=0).values('id', 'topic__name')[:10]
form = WallPostForm(data)
```

I get a `'WallPostForm' object has no attribute 'fields'` error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django sets up the form's `fields` property in the `__init__`.

So just swap your code:

```
def __init__(self, data):
    super(WallPostForm, self).__init__()
    self.fields['relates_to'] = forms.ChoiceField(label=u'Relates to', choices=data, widget=forms.Select(), required=False)
```

Though, you probably shouldn't override a `Form`'s `__init__` like that. Django's form system expects the `data` arg in init to contain the data for the form, not a queryset you're using for a choices field.

I'd override it differently:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    relates_to_queryset = kwargs.pop('relates_to_queryset')
    super(WallPostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['relates_to'] = forms.ChoiceField(label=u'Relates to', choices=relates_to_queryset, widget=forms.Select(), required=False)
```

Then call it:

```
form = WallPostForm(request.POST or None, relates_to_queryset=data)
```

Answer (score 4):

As an addition to Jack's answer, you're probably better off just replacing the `choices` attribute, rather than the whole field:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    relates_to_choices = kwargs.pop('relates_to_choices')
    super(WallPostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['relates_to'].choices = relates_to_choices
```

(I renamed the variable, it won't be a queryset.)

Comment: that is true. Thanks for your input. I am sorry I can't accept both answers as correct.

Answer (score -1):

You can use "initial" parameter, see the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.initial