# Django: How to model users with different mandatory fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I'm new to Django and I'm trying to implement a project where companies can register as users. As the companies may come from different countries and have different corporate forms they have some different mandatory fields when registering. The differences are only informational and have no consequence on the behaviour, i.e. all users should be treated equally after the registration. At the moment I only need to support 2 countries and 2 corporate forms but maybe more should be supported in the future.
I started with a single company model in form of a user-profile (one-to-one relationship with user) but in that case I have to set the fields which are different between company forms and countries as nullable and handle the correct input in the forms?
Furthermore I want to see all users (companies) in one single list in the admin.

How would you model that in Django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django form is very flexible in fields manipulation. You could always add/remove `required` from a field, or even delete a field from a form on the fly. All you need is to pass a parameter to the form constructor `__init__()`. Here's a basic example:

```
class BlahForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Blah
        fields = ('field1', 'field2',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        param = kwargs.pop('param', None)
        super(BlahForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # how to mark a field as "not required"
        if param == 'not_required':
            self.fields['field1'].required = False
        # here's how to delete a field
        elif param == 'delete_field':
            del self.fields['field1']
```

In the views.py you can initialize your form like this:

```
if 'condition1':
    form = BlahForm(request.POST or None, param='not_required')
elif 'condition2':
    form = BlahForm(required.POST or None, param='delete_field')
```

Your form would behave depends on that parameter you passed in, thus you only need one form for all countries(as you said the differences are trivial). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! That's exactly what I was looking for the approach using only one company model. I can pass a parameter identifying the country and company and customise the form according to the parameter. There is just one last issue with that. I have some custom form fields, e.g. from django-flavors, that are different for each country and I can't use the passed parameter for that.

Comment: I found the answer to that last issue. I can also create the appropriate field in __init__ according to the passed parameter: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086175/django-set-choicefield-in-form-after-creation).